# React, call class function from within another function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My React Component has a couple functions within it.

I want to call the logResults() function from within the Google Maps Geocoder function, but am told "TypeError: this.log is not a function"

```
  getLatLong(address){
    const google = window.google
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      let lat; let long;
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        long = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
      }
      this.logResults(lat, long);
    })
  }

  logResults(lat, long){
    console.log(lat + "" + long)
  }
```

I know I'm doing something stupid here but can't figure it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: this.logResults exists in the scope of the class. Currently it's in the scope of google maps class. So, create a variable outside of the geocode function like so `var logResults = this.logResults;` and you should be able to call it without the **this** argument.

Comment: Yup. That was it. So simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to bind the context. All non arrow functions will require you to `bind(this)`.

```
  getLatLong(address){
    const google = window.google
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      let lat; let long;
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        long = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
      }
      this.logResults(lat, long);
    }.bind(this))
  }

  logResults(lat, long){
    console.log(lat + "" + long)
  }
```

OR

ES6

```
  getLatLong(address){
    const google = window.google
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, (results, status) => {
      let lat; let long;
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        long = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
      }
      this.logResults(lat, long);
    })
  }

  logResults(lat, long){
    console.log(lat + "" + long)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that using a callback function defined with the `function` keyword introduces a new `this` context. You can fix this by using an arrow function (if you can use es6):

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, (results, status) => {
  let lat; let long;
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    long = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
  }
  this.logResults(lat, long);
})
```

Or if you can't to that, pass your `this` in using a closure:

```
let self = this;
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
  let lat; let long;
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    long = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
  }
  self.logResults(lat, long);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` is referring to your inner anonymous function. In order for `this` to refer to your main object, you need to bind it to your anonymous function. Something like this:

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      let lat; let long;
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        long = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
      }
      this.logResults(lat, long);
    }.bind(this) )
```

Whatever you pass to a function via bind(), will become `this` inside that function. In above case, we are sending your beloved `this` from parent function, to become `this` in child function. bind() creates "Family Bonding" :)